# Dynamic html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two html pages. And one ccs file. I need to know is there any way to copy all content inside div tags in one html to any others html. For example

Css file:

```
#block {
/* some code that doesn't matter */
}
```

Main html:

```
<div id="block">
Some text inside div called "block" that is need to be showed in any others html pages with the
same div "block"
</div>
```

Sub html page:

```
<div id="block">
Code that's need to be placed once to read all content from div "block"
</div>
```

Comment: call page from ajaxcall and then after parsing put in other

Answer (score 1):

Look into Conditionally Loading data http://24ways.org/2011/conditional-loading-for-responsive-designs, http://adactio.com/journal/4497/ & http://adactio.com/journal/5042/